# RubyでJSONを要素の順番によらず同一判定したい

Tags: ruby, json

RubyでJSONデータを各要素の順番によらず、同じ要素が含まれていれば（連想配列の場合はキーと値の組み合わせが同じであれば）同一と判定したいと思っています。

以下のようなコードを考えていますが、もっとシンプルなやり方があれば教えてください。
（目的は同一判定なのでソート以外のやり方でも構いません）

```
def json_sort(json)
  # jsonから生成したRubyオブジェクトを再帰的にソートする
  case json
  when Array
    # 配列の場合はソートし、json_sortを各要素に適用
    json.sort.map{|v|json_sort(v)}
  when Hash
    # 連想配列の場合はキーでソートした上でjson_sortを各要素に適用
    Hash[json.sort.map{|(k,v)|[k, json_sort(v)]}]
  else; json
  end
end

a = JSON.parse('{"a": 1, "b": [1, 2]}')
b = JSON.parse('{"b": [2, 1], "a": 1}')
json_sort(a) == json_sort(b) #=> 順番が違っても同一と判定したい
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrayを順番によらず同一視したいということは、RubyのArrayに展開されるのが間違っていると言う事だと思います。この場合はSetが望むものではないでしょうか？

array_classオプションで配列をどのクラスにするか指定できる(http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/method/JSON=3a=3aParser/s/new.html)ので、それを使う事で以下のようにかけます。

```
require 'set'
a = JSON.parse('{"a": 1, "b": [1, 2]}',array_class: Set)
b = JSON.parse('{"b": [2, 1], "a": 1}',array_class: Set)
p a,b,a==b
```

ただし、Setだと`[1,1,2]`が`[1,2]`と同じに扱われてしまうので、それだと不味い場合は、

```
class CustomArray < Array
  def ==(a)
    self.sort == a.sort
  end
end
a = JSON.parse('{"a": 1, "b": [1, 2]}',array_class: CustomArray)
b = JSON.parse('{"b": [2, 1], "a": 1}',array_class: CustomArray)
```

とすると質問と同じ結果を出すコードになりますし、またはSetから入力をvalidateするクラスを作ってそれを用いるのもありえると思います。

Comment: Setクラス初めて知りました！
重複が消えるのは気になりますが、後のやり方の応用で思ったことが出来そうです。
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 3):

スマホからなのでソースは少ししか示せませんが、

もともとHashを`==`で比較するときは順序が違っても比較してくれますよね。
ということは現状はArrayが問題で(配列の並びが違うものを同じとして良いかという議論はあるかもしれませんがそれは置いておいて)、JSONであれば複雑なオブジェクトも来ないだろうかと思います(そこの前提がだめだったらごめんなさい)。

そこで、もとのハッシュをディープコピーしたうえで、現在と同様中身を検査してArrayを破壊的なソートをしていくほうが、少しはシンプルになるようなきがします。

deep コピーは

```
dup_a = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
dup_b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(b))
```

とできます。
そして配列だけソートして比較すれば

```
dup_a["b"].sort! 
dup_b["b"].sort!
p dup_a==dup_b
```

結果はtrueです。

ハッシュの中のすべての配列の並び変えを関数化すると、結局今と同じような再帰呼び出しとなってしまいますが、
再帰中のハッシュのソートと生成(when Hash部分)の簡略化はできるんじゃないかと思います。

Comment: なるほど、ソート処理の対象はArrayに絞り込めばよいということですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

参考情報を紹介します。
stackoverflow に次のページがありました。

- Canonicalizing JSON files　https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584744/canonicalizing-json-files

他にも net 上で "canonical json" を検索すると、類似の問題について情報が得られます。

Comment: 恐縮ですが、katoyさんの知っている知識の範囲で回答いただけますでしょうか。
質問の前に、貼っていただいた記事も見ていましたが、javaやpythonのコードも混じっていたり、rubyのコードも自分の貼ったコードより冗長で参考にならないです。

ただ、"canonical json"という検索ワードは知らなかったので助かります！